# Выдать на печать те слова , перед которыми находятся слова только меньшие по алфавиту , а за ними только большие

Tags: c#, compare

Я в программировании новенькая, и не могу решить эту задачу. Задумка была, что надо слово сравнить со всеми словами после него и если оно меньше всех следующих, то окей, и сравнить с предыдущими и если до него все слова меньше то его надо вывести, сколько хожу вокруг не могу додуматься что ещё нужно сделать, во что смогла придумать, помогите пожалуйста

```
string[] words = str.Split(new char[] { ' ', ',', '.', ':', '!', '?', '@', '$', '%', '&' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    ring result = " ";
        bool flag1 = false;
        bool flag2 = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i+1; j < words.Length; j++)
            {
                 if (words[i].CompareTo(words[j]) > 0)
                 {
                      flag1 = false;
                      continue;
                 }
                 else if(words[i].CompareTo(words[j]) <= 0)
                 {
                      flag1 = true;
                 }
            }
            for (int j = i; j >= 0; j--)
            {
                 if (words[i].CompareTo(words[j]) < 0)
                 {
                      flag2 = false;
                      continue;
                 }
                 else if (words[i].CompareTo(words[j]) >= 0)
                 {
                      flag2 = true;
                 }
            }


             if (flag1 && flag2)
             {
                 result += words[i] + " ";
             }


        }
        Console.Write(result);
```

Comment: Вообще не очень понятно, в каком месте у вас слово, которое необходимо сравнить

Comment: По алфавиту, это значит что в примере: `"Привет, мир! Нам необходимо вывести любое слово!"` будут выведены слова: "Нам" и "любое" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если добавить переменную, хранящую самое большое слово (или его индекс) на текущий момент, то цикл назад (с flag2) не потребуется. Кроме того, flag1 нужно инициализировать на каждой итерации.

```
    string currentmax = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
    {
        bool flag1 = true;
        for (int j = i+1; j < words.Length; j++)
        {
             if (words[i].CompareTo(words[j]) >= 0)
             {
                  flag1 = false;
                  break;
             }
        }
        if (words[i].CompareTo(currentmax) > 0) {
            currentmax = words[i];
            if (flag1)
                print it;
        }  
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

По идее, как-то так:

```
    void Main()
    {
    string[] arr = new string[10];
    var prevWords=new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        if (WordNeedPrint(arr[i], arr, i + 1,prevWords))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);
        }
        prevWords.Add(arr[i]);
    }
}

bool WordNeedPrint(string word, string[] arr, int idx,List<string> prevWords)
{
    for (int i = idx; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        if (word.CompareTo(arr[i]) < 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return prevWords.All(x=>word.CompareTo(x) < 0);
}
```

Comment: Но это же неполноценное решение

Comment: @MBo а что я упустил?

Comment: Как я понимаю, здесь проверяются только слова после текущего. Но если перед ним будет большее, то выводить ведь не надо.

Comment: @MBo тогда, наверное, как-то так.

Comment: Зачем извращения плодите? ;)))